# Python 3.x -PPTX Why template.pptx object has no attribute 'slides_layouts'

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, python-pptx

I know this module is not very popular but if you know the answer then please help me out with it.

My code is:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('do.pptx')
title_slide_layout = prs.slides_layouts[0]
# print(len(prs.slide.slide_layout.shapes))
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Python 3.6 - Turtle Race"
subtitle.text = "Data Analytics&Visualization with random generated data"

prs.save("out.pptx")
```

My Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton/turtleRace/presentationMaker.py", line 8, in <module>
    title_slide_layout = prs.slides_layouts[0]
AttributeError: 'Presentation' object has no attribute 'slides_layouts'
```

[A picture of my project interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQYDi.png)

So Why I have this error?

Comment: The name you're looking for is `prs.slide_layouts` (no "s" after 'slide'). And btw, `python-pptx` is _extremely_ popular :)

Comment: Okay thank you I will try it!!

Comment: **Thank you it helped me a lot! There is no error now!**